# Using elasticsearch dsl query with multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I run a query with myindex(dota2) as you see below:
[image]

But I need indices is inside the query, so I include it as the docs in elasticsearch.co in my dsl query, and run it but all the indices return(Ijust want the make query just in two indices 'dota2','dota3') here:
[image]

What do I wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your case is that when you use the [`indices` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-indices-query.html), you also need to specify the `no_match_query` part to `none` otherwise `all` documents from the non-matching indices will be returned.

However, you could also simply write your URL as follows:

```
GET dota2,dota3/_search
```

Comment: Hello, can you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907090/elasticsearch-custom-analyzer-pattern Thank you Val.